# firebase phoneauth- returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzal@830b094

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

As I said in the title it used to work fine but suddenly it doesn't anymore, I'm not getting any errors in 'Run' so I really can't locate where the probleme is

here is my gradle:

```
       apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.nearmessenger"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/hani-momanii/maven" }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-emoji-appcompat:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-emoji-bundled:28.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha02'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha03'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.+'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.6'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.3.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:15.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.2-alpha01'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.2-alpha01'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

as well as I'm getting this feedback when i click on the send code button in 'RUN':

```
W/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzal@830b094
```

Comment: I have the same problem, but sometimes I got sms code in some devices

Comment: You can have a look [at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53428463/2289835)