# Firebase Phone Authentication: onCodeSent is not called

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

My code:

```
PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
            phoneNumber,        // Phone number to verify
            60,                 // Timeout duration
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
            this,               // Activity (for callback binding)
            new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
                @Override
                public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onCodeSent(String s, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
                    super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);

                    otpSent = s;
                    Log.d("AuthTest", "code sent!");
                }
            });
```

Here the phone number is entered in international format (+91 and 10 digits for India). Here, onCodeSent is not called if the user selects a valid phone number of his choice. On the other hand, if I go to Firebase console and enter a phone number for testing, 
[image]
onCodeSent is executed.

I was following a YouTube tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N6HBStmDkMQ). Many people have asked this developer about the same problem "OTP (i.e, verification code) is not received". Author has not responded.

What's happening here? Has Firebase changed anything or set a limitation on free accounts, or am I missing something?

Comment: add some log into your `onVerificationFailed` and check if there is an error

Comment: It is likely instant validation is triggered. `onVerificationCompleted` is getting triggered instead.

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53428463/2289835)

Answer (score 1):

The issue was of registering the app in the Firebase. Package name and SHA-1 key are needed. This I came to know by intercepting the `FirebaseException` at `onVerificationFailed` callback as @Tamir Abutbul suggested. Once the app was registered, it started working.

Also, when I tried to run the app from my other Android Studio environment on a different mac, the app registration issue cropped again. This time it told me the SHA-1 key that I entered earlier was not from this mac. So I had to generate another key and add it (you can add multiple keys).