# Mobile OTP Verification without signing in using Firebase Phone Auth

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am currently making an android app where I need to verify if the user is entering correct mobile number using the OTP.
The user is already signed in the application using his email and password.
Now I need to verify the mobile number the user enters without using the signInWithCrendntial() method of firebase phone auth.
How do i go about it ?

My mCallbacks is

```
                @Override
                public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Verification Complete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    showMessage("Success!!","OTP verified!" + credential);
                    cred = credential;
                    //btn_add_guest.setEnabled(true);

                }

                @Override
                public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Verification Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.i(TAG,"Error is "+e.getMessage());
                }

                @Override
                public void onCodeSent(String verificationId,
                                       PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Code Sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    mVerificationId = verificationId;
                    mResendToken = token;

                    Log.i(TAG,"VERFICATION ID IS"+mVerificationId);
                    Log.i(TAG,"RESEND TOKEN"+mResendToken);
                    btn_add_guest.setEnabled(false);
                }
            };
```

I m calling this method on button Pressed where put_otp is textView where user enters the OTP.

```
verifyPhoneNumberWithCode(mVerificationId,put_otp.getText().toString());
                    PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(mVerificationId, put_otp.getText().toString());
                    Log.i(TAG,credential.getProvider());

private void verifyPhoneNumberWithCode(String verificationId, String code) {

        Log.i(TAG,"RESEND TOKEN IN METHOD IS"+mResendToken);    if(code.equals(mResendToken)&&verificationId.equals(mVerificationId)){
            Toast.makeText(AddGuestActivity.this, "Verification Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            btn_add_guest.setEnabled(true);
        }
        else
            Toast.makeText(this,"Please provide correct OTP",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: For mobile number enter is there different screen??

Comment: Mobile number is on the same screen. There is no different screen for the same.

Comment: You should have a look [at this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53428463/2289835)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can link an email/pass account with a phone account https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking?authuser=0

Comment: This answer should be marked as the correct answer, thanks Markymark