# Phone Auth Cardential can not be accessed from outside the package

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to add phone authentication in my android project using firebase data base system but I am  facing problem with "PhoneAuth Cardential". It shows phone auth credential can not be resolved and phone auth cardentila can not be accessed from outside package.I  want to authenticate user using code send on contact number being entered by the user so that after authentication user should be allowed to login.

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseException;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Log_in extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MaterialEditText phoneEditText;
    private EditText editText;
    private Button continueButton, sendCode;
    private TextView mainTextView,miniTextVeiw;

    private String phoneNumber;
private boolean phoneAndCode=false;

    private String verificationID;
    private PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken resendToken;


    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks callbacksInstance;

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_log_in);
        phoneEditText = (MaterialEditText) findViewById(R.id.phoneEditText);
        continueButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.continueButton);

        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        sendCode = (Button) findViewById(R.id.code);

        mainTextView=findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        miniTextVeiw=findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


        sendCode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });
    }


    public void onContinueClick(View v) {


        if(phoneAndCode==false)
        {
            if (phoneEditText.getText().toString() != null && phoneEditText.getText().toString().length() == 11) {

                final DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                phoneNumber = phoneEditText.getText().toString();
                phoneNumber="+92"+phoneNumber.substring(1);

                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
                progressDialog.setTitle("please wait");
                progressDialog.setMessage("sending code");
                progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    //            phoneVerifier();
                if (MainActivity.flag == 1) {
                    databaseReference.child("Driver").child(phoneNumber).setValue(null);
                    phoneVerifier();

                } else if (MainActivity.flag == 0) {
              //      Toast.makeText(this,"called for driver and phone number is"+phoneNumber,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    databaseReference.child("Passenger").child(phoneNumber).setValue(null);
                    phoneVerifier();

                }
phoneAndCode=true;

            } else {
                phoneEditText.setError("invalid phone number");
            }
        }
        else if(phoneAndCode==true)
        {
            String verificationCode = null;
            PhoneAuthCredential credential = null;
            if (!(phoneEditText.getText().toString().equals(null))) {
                verificationCode = phoneEditText.getText().toString();
                credential = new PhoneAuthCredential(verificationID, verificationCode);
                signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
            } else
                phoneEditText.setError("invalid verification code");

        }


    }

    private void phoneVerifier() {

        progressDialog.show();
        callbacksInstance = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

            @Override
            public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
                signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(phoneAuthCredential);
            }

            @Override
            public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
                Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.welcomeRoot), "invalid phone number", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //if the phone number is wrong;


            }

            public void onCodeSent(String verificationId,
                                   PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token) {
                // The SMS verification code has been sent to the provided phone number, we
                // now need to ask the user to enter the code and then construct a credential
                // by combining the code with a verification ID.
                Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.welcomeRoot), "code sent", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                // Save verification ID and resending token so we can use them later
                verificationID = verificationId;
                resendToken = token;


                progressDialog.dismiss();
               // continueButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            //    sendCode.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                continueButton.setText("Send verification code");
                mainTextView.setText("Enter verification code that you have recently received");
                miniTextVeiw.setText("Enter verification code");
                phoneEditText.setHint("enter verification code");
                phoneEditText.setText(null);

                // ...
            }
        };
        PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                phoneNumber,        // Phone number to verify
                60,                 // Timeout duration
                TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
                this,               // Activity (for callback binding)
                callbacksInstance);        // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks

    }

    private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
        firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information

                            FirebaseUser user = task.getResult().getUser();
                            if (MainActivity.flag == 0) {
                                startActivity(new Intent(Log_in.this, DriverMapsActivity.class));
                                finish();
                            } else if (MainActivity.flag == 1) {
                                startActivity(new Intent(Log_in.this, CustomerMapsActivity.class));
                                finish();
                            }
                            // ...
                        } else {
                            // Sign in failed, display a message and update the UI
                            Toast.makeText(Log_in.this, "sign in failed try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                                // The verification code entered was invalid
                                Toast.makeText(Log_in.this, "You have enterd an INVALID CODE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

    }

}
```

Comment: You can find complete [solution here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53428463/2289835) Kindly have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try this line

```
credential =PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationID,verificationCode);
```

instead of

```
credential = new PhoneAuthCredential(verificationID, verificationCode);
```