# Firebase SMS Verification / Authentication not working on some devices

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase SMS verification for Authentication. The code works fine on most of the devices but it shows `'com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException'` on **OPPO A37fw**.

This is my code and it  works fine on every devices including other Oppo devices .Only On OPPO A37fw this error is shown.

```
 PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks callbacks
        = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
    @Override
    public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onVerificationCompleted:" + credential);
        MobileVerification.credential = credential;
        openOTPvalidation(ON_VERIFICATION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
        postException(context, TAG, e);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCodeSent(String s, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token) {
        super.onCodeSent(s, token);
        verificationCode    = s;
        forceResendingToken = token;
        openOTPvalidation(OTP_SEND);
    }
};

private void getOTP() {
    if (activity != null) {
        pDialog = SupportingMethods.showDialogLoading(activity);
        pDialog.show();
    }
    String mobile   = "+91" + mob;
    PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
            mobile,        // Phone number to verify
            60,                 // Timeout duration
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
            activity,               // Activity (for callback binding)
            callbacks);        // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
}
```

And the Logcat shows :

```
   com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException: This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication. Please verifythat the correct package name and SHA-1 are configured in the Firebase Console. [ App validation failed ] 
        at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzdr.zzb(Unknown Source) 
        at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzet.zza(Unknown Source) 
        at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzew.run(Unknown Source) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5541) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:964) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:759) 
        ************ DEVICE INFORMATION *********** 
        Brand: OPPO 
        Device: A37f 
        Model: A37fw 
        Id: LMY47V 
        Product: A37fw
```

Comment: Seems like SH1 key is not mentioned in the firebase project. and if you did it already then try to login with test number which you can define in Authentication -> Sign-in method -> Phone -> Phone numbers for testing (optional).
and if you can't sign in with the real number then maybe your number has reached maximum limit to request OTP.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53513327/2289835) and [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53428463/2289835)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have connected firebase with the help of android assistant these kind of issues may show up.So you need to download a new copy of google-services.json file from firbase console and add it to your project folder. This might help you.