# I try to implement a phone authentification using firebase but i don t receive any sms

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I am trying to implement a firebase auth method using phone number but when I click the button to receive my sms code, the progress bar just loads and I don t get any sms. Nor does any account get created on the Firebase Console since I can't register my account if I don't enter my verification code.

RegisterLoginActivity

```
package com.example.madistrezsieu

import android.content.Intent

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseException
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthCredential
import com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_register_login.*
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit


class RegisterLoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var mCallbacks: PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
    lateinit var mAuth: FirebaseAuth
    var verificationId = ""


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register_login)
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        veriBtn.setOnClickListener {
                view: View? -> progress.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            verify ()
        }
        authBtn.setOnClickListener {
                view: View? -> progress.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            authenticate()
        }
    }


    private fun verificationCallbacks () {
        mCallbacks = object: PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
            override fun onVerificationCompleted(credential: PhoneAuthCredential) {
                progress.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                signIn(credential)
            }

            override fun onVerificationFailed(p0: FirebaseException?) {
                //TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }

            override fun onCodeSent(verfication: String?, p1: PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken?) {
                super.onCodeSent(verfication, p1)
                verificationId = verfication.toString()
                progress.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            }

        }
    }

    private fun verify () {

        verificationCallbacks()

        val phnNo = phnNoTxt.text.toString()

        PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
            phnNo,
            60,
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,
            this,
            mCallbacks
        )
    }

    private fun signIn (credential: PhoneAuthCredential) {
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener {
                    task: Task<AuthResult> ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    toast("Logged in Successfully :)")
                    startActivity(Intent(this, LatestMessagesActivity::class.java))
                }
            }
    }

    private fun authenticate () {

        val verifiNo = verifiTxt.text.toString()

        val credential: PhoneAuthCredential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId, verifiNo)

        signIn(credential)

    }

    private fun toast (msg: String) {
        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }


}
```

activity_register_login.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context="com.example.madistrezsieu.RegisterLoginActivity">

    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/phnNoTxt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="88dp"
            android:hint="Phone Number"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/verifiTxt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:layout_below="@+id/phnNoTxt"
            android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
            android:hint="Verification Code" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/veriBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/verifiTxt"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
            android:text="Verify" />

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/authBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/veriBtn"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
            android:text="Authenticate" />

    <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/phnNoTxt"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: did you enable phone authentication from firebase console?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53428463/2289835) and [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53513327/2289835)

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you enabled phone authentication on firebase console,
2. Make sure your project on android studio connected to firebase because phone authentication need SHA-1 certificate to send sms. Your android studio will handle SHA-1 automatically.
3. sometimes there is a problem when connecting firebase to android project through android studio, in this case you should create manually your own SHA-1 for your project. follow this link to do it [SHA-1 fingerprint of keystore certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727912/sha-1-fingerprint-of-keystore-certificate)

Comment: The Firebase Auth with Phone is enabled, i also introduced my SHA-1 Debug that I got from Android Studio, still doesn't work.