# How can i resolve this problem in Android studio - Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

How can i resolve this problem in Android studio - Flutter  - dart
Iam using Android studio, flutter, firebase

```
 Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
    √ Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
    Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:56274/zuPzwT257Jk=/ws
    Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
    D/EGL_emulation(19266): eglMakeCurrent: 0xa9d06620: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa9d03620)
    I/BiChannelGoogleApi(19266): [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzaq@3211e85
    W/DynamiteModule(19266): Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
    W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(19266): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 12451000 but found 11743470
```

Answer (score 0):

updating the googlePlayService should solve the problem.

If its your emulator than you can try this way

[image]

Comment: Ok. Thank you.. And you know about the error W/DynamiteModule(20787): Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.

Comment: it looks similar to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43422021/android-auth-firebase-error-local-module-descriptor-class-for-com-google-fireba)
You might find your ans there.