# Flutter with Firebase Error - signInWithEmailAndPassword doesn't work

Tags: firebase, flutter, authentication

Some firebase problem with other credential

```
I/BiChannelGoogleApi( 2705): [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzaq@175a1c6
    W/DynamiteModule( 2705): Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
    W/GooglePlayServicesUtil( 2705): Google Play Store is missing.
    I/flutter ( 2705): PlatformException(ERROR_API_NOT_AVAILABLE, API: InternalFirebaseAuth.FIREBASE_AUTH_API is not available on this device. Connection failed with: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE_INVALID, resolution=null, message=null}, null)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To get accurate answers, you should write what you're trying to achieve, attach a portion of code and explain what have you tried in order to fix the issues

Answer (score 2):

Searching for *Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.* led me to the related [fixes described in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43422021/11127519). I think this error can be caused by any of the following:

- Incorrect version of Google Play Services for Android
- Missing or incorrect SHA values in your Firebase project configuration
- Incorrect Firebase Auth version

Personally I would check your SHA-1 config first.

Comment: Thanks for contributing, but please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer - the links you posted could disappear and then this answer becomes useless.

Comment: Is it mandatory to link our firebase with SHA-1?

Comment: When using Firebase Auth or Google Play Services you will be required to create a signing certificate and add the SHA-1 value of this certificate to your Firebase project configuration. Hope this helps.

Comment: I follow the instruction and now I get this error

I/flutter ( 1854): MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method signInAnonymously on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth)
I/flutter ( 1854): null